# Display image inside the box without stretching it

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I developed an image gallery.

My problem is that I am using 100% height and sometimes the image stretches, ending up losing quality.

Is there a way to place the image in the center of the box without stretching it and in the center if it is not tall enough to fill the box completely?

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ul7mpd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**My code**

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="drop dropp">
            <div class="abc">
                <ngb-carousel style="outline: none;" id="carousel" #carousel *ngIf="data" data-interval="false"
                    data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover" (slide)="change($event)">
                    <ng-template *ngFor="let imgIdx of data; let i = index" [id]="i" ngbSlide>
                        <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
                            <img [src]="imgIdx.image" style="border-radius: 8px; object-fit: fill;" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                    </ng-template>
                </ngb-carousel>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="Upcard" *ngFor="let imgIdx of belowImageData; let i = index">
                <img class="img-responsive" [src]="imgIdx.image" style="width: 100%; object-fit: fill; height: 100%; border-radius: 8px;">
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**My Problem **

As you can see in the image, it fills the whole box but is deformed :( I want it not to lose quality and if it doesn't have enough height, stay centered on the box. I want the box to have a fixed height.

Comment: Object fit should be cover and not fill

Comment: @Wimanicesir 
But if the image has a very low height and width it will not be stretched using this option?

Comment: If we use object-fit: cover; it will cut off the sides of the image, preserving the aspect ratio, and also filling in the space

Comment: @Wimanicesir 
I think my problem is in the abc class at height: 100%; If you put it in auto the image is never deformed. I just can't centered on the div.  
I tested it but in some images it ends up losing a lot of quality

Comment: If an image is smaller than the container. It will become bigger than it's original. So either you lose quality or show the image on its original format. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the old browsers you can use object-fit property on the img directly.

for example:

```
object-fit: cover;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Otherwise you can add an empty div, give it the full size of the box, and use the image as a background of that div. Then use background-size property.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But if the image has a very low height and width it will not be stretched using this option?

Comment: It should fit the whole parent container (or itself if img). The shortest side will be fully visible and if the longest is bigger than the container depending on the ratio it will cut from it. But if you don't want it cut, maybe you should use object-fit/background-size: contain.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the code, you can try adding the below code in css.edit and take a look

```
 .img-responsive {
  object-fit: contain; height:200px!important;
}
```

or to need all images to fit properly you have to remove the div global height 100 percentage. and set the height specific for each div. so you don't need height parameter in .img-responsive class.

Comment: I don't want to give the image a fixed height and I want it to be centered, but thanks to try help me

Comment: can you test "object-fit: contain;"  insted of cover

Comment: I think my problem is in the abc class at height: 100%; If you put it in auto the image is never deformed. I just can't centered on the div